# Improve function to recognize and convert unicode emojis

Tags: php, regex, unicode, emoji

I have this function to convert **hashtag** and **mentions**.

```
<?php 

function convertAll($str) {
    $regex = "/[@#](\w+)/";
    //type and links
    $hrefs = [
        '#' => 'hashtag?tag',
        '@' => 'profile?username'
    ];

    $result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use ($hrefs) {
         return sprintf(
             '<a href="%s=%s">%s</a>',
             $hrefs[$matches[0][0]],
             $matches[1], 
             $matches[0]
         );
    }, $str);

    return($result);
}

$text = "text example - #php text here @test text here";
//emoji list http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html
//echo "\u{emoj};
//emoji test
echo '<div style="font-size: 100px;">';
echo "\u{1F30F}";
echo '</div>';
//function only
echo convertAll($text);
```

**UNICODE EMOJI**: http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html

So based on my echo Unicode example, I need to replace a Unicode code-point corresponding to an emoji with the Unicode character.

For example:
I want to replace `U+1F617` with `\u{1F617}`

Given a UNICODE code-point in the format U+XXXXX I want to replace it with an actual UNICODE character using regular expression. How could I do this?

Comment: did you not ask this (or a similar question) within the last 30 mins?

Comment: but question was closed and I updated the question

Comment: From what I can see, there is no additional content within the question that won't stop this Q from also being closed ..

Comment: I added the unicode list `echo '<div style=font-size: 100px;">';
    echo "\u{1F30F}";
    echo '</div>';`

Comment: [The exact dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414299/improve-function-to-recognize-and-convert-emoj) for reference (which OP has kindly just deleted)

Comment: What exactly is the desired result?  All you're doing above is outputting an emoji.  I see no attempt to "covert" it to anything, and it is unclear _to what_ you want it to be converted.

Comment: I need to get all emoji on the list http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html  and convert unicode text to emoj inside the function

Comment: What is a *unicode text*? An emoji is a unicode character

Comment: yeah, I need a regex impplementation

Comment: What do you want to do with emojis? What is your desired output and what is your input? An emoji is a letter just like any other letter e.g. a, b, c or 汉语

Comment: this is the output `echo "\u{1F30F}";`

Comment: What does "convert unicode text to emoj " mean to you though?  Do you mean that you want to replace "\u{1F62C}" with "&#128556"?

Comment: No, this is your PHP code. The output would be 

Comment: Patrick Q  I want to replace `U+1F617` to  `\u{1F617}`

Comment: So to be clear, you would have an input like `text example - #php text here @test text here followed by emoji U+1F617` and you want the converted result to be `text example - <a href="hashtag?tag=php">#php</a> text here <a href="profile?username=test">@test</a> text here followed by emoji \u{1F617}`  Is that correct?

Comment: exactly but I need a regex repression to get the emoj and add it into a array to next convert and output by the function

Comment: To sum it up: Given a UNICODE code-point in the format U+XXXXX you want it to be replaced with an actual UNICODE character using regular expression. Correct?

Comment: @Dharman exactly!

Comment: Can't post an answer since this is on hold, but basically you can use `preg_replace("/U\+([A-F0-9]*)/", '\u{${1}}', $text)`.  You can't do it within the `preg_replace_callback()` since that is assuming all matches are to be converted to links, which the emojis are not.

Comment: Inside your `convertAll()`, you'd use `$result` instead of `$text`, and call it after your `preg_replace_callback()` call

Comment: IMO this cannot be opened in its present state: "I just need help to make it fully functional and as simple as possible" is a request to do the whole thing. I would suggest, as a minimum, that this sentence is removed and replaced with something _much_ more specific. The same goes for "someone know a simple example to also add emoji on it" - it is just too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current use of `preg_replace_callback()` assumes that all regex matches will be replaced with a link.  Since the emojis will not be used as part of a link, the simples solution is to leave the `preg_replace_callback()` as-is, an add an extra step after that where we do the unicode replacement.

```
function convertAll($str) {
    $regex = "/[@#](\w+)/";
    //type and links
    $hrefs = [
        '#' => 'hashtag?tag',
        '@' => 'profile?username'
    ];

    $result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use ($hrefs) {
         return sprintf(
             '<a href="%s=%s">%s</a>',
             $hrefs[$matches[0][0]],
             $matches[1], 
             $matches[0]
         );
    }, $str);

    $result = preg_replace("/U\+([A-F0-9]{5})/", '\u{${1}}', $result);

    return($result);
}
```

The regex part of the `preg_replace()` is saying to match a literal "U" followed by a literal "+" followed by 5 instances of any characters A-Z or 0-9.  We are capturing those 5 characters and putting them after a literal "\u{" and then following them with a literal "}".

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6793d974a7a18a0c3d8df63b929d9314310ba7a0)

There may be a way to do this within `preg_replace_callback()`, but that seemed a bit more effort than I was willing to put in right now.  If someone comes up with an answer that does that, I'd love to see it.

To replace with HTML entities use this `preg_replace` instead:

```
$result = preg_replace("/U\+([A-F0-9]{5})/", "&#x\\1;", $result);
```

Comment: Very cool, but it's not showing as emoji in html, why? simple `echo "\u{1F30F}";` would show just fine

Comment: something like `echo convertAll($text)`; is not returning as `echo "\u{1F30F}"` , browser here shows as plain text , not emoji

Comment: @OtávioBarreto  That is why I made [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415065/improve-function-to-recognize-and-convert-unicode-emojis/57416815#comment101310769_57415065) earlier.  If what you really care about is HTML display, that is most likely what you want.

Comment: so it would be `&#128556;` how to achieve HTML Entities ?

Comment: Depending on what the input is, yes, that would be the general format.  That would obviously be different replacement/conversion logic.  Also, the reason why `echo "\u{1F30F}"` results in the actual emoji image on your screen is https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax .  The `preg_replace()` seems to remove the benefit of that escaping.

Comment: @OtávioBarreto  See the update at the end of the answer

Comment: Great example, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  This is why it is so important that you are clear about what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: do you think would be a problem if I filter from database with `htmlentities();` before pass the text to the function?

Comment: That's a bit outside the scope of this question I think.  If you have further problems, feel free to open new questions.

Comment: I tested and it works fine I just need to call `htmlentities();` before to pass the text variable to  `convertAll()` function

Comment: Another question, now the reverse, convert  this  into this `U+1F603` can you help ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447226/convert-emoji-character-to-unicode-codepoint-number-in-php