# convert emoji character to Unicode codepoint number in php

Tags: php, html, function, unicode, emoji

I am trying to convert emoji to unicode with php 
, more info: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

How to convert this  into  this `U+1F603` with php?

```
function convert_emoji($var){

}
```

Comment: I solved my own question btw.

Comment: can only mark as solved in 2 days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a simple way to solve, so I will answer my own question, but if somebody would like to improve this function, would be cool.

```
<?php

function emoji_to_unicode($emoji) {
   $emoji = mb_convert_encoding($emoji, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
   $unicode = strtoupper(preg_replace("/^[0]+/","U+",bin2hex($emoji)));
   return $unicode;
}

$var = "";
echo emoji_to_unicode($var);


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Intl` extension provides [a function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intlchar.ord.php) to return the codepoint for a character. As it returns an integer, you just need to convert it to a hex string.

```
function emoji_to_unicode($emoji) {
    return sprintf('U+%X', IntlChar::ord($emoji));
}
```